# pandas average bin values across all indices

Tags: pandas

I have a data wrangling question that I am stumped on. I am trying to group data into specified bins and take the average of a cumsum:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( data = {'year':np.arange(1800,2000,1),'var1':np.random.randint(0,20,200),'var2':np.random.randint(0,20,200)})
thresholds = np.arange(0,20,1)
bins = pd.cut(df.var2, thresholds)

grouped = df.groupby(['year', bins]).count()
grouped = grouped.fillna(0)
grouped = grouped.assign(Num_Events = grouped.groupby('var1').var2.cumsum())

grouped = grouped.unstack()
```

I want to take the average of `Num_Events` across all calendar years specified in the index of `grouped`' for each bin (i.e. column).   `grouped['Num_Events'].head()` looks like:

```
var2  (0, 1]  (1, 2]  (2, 3]  (3, 4]  ...  (15, 16]  (16, 17]  (17, 18]  (18, 19]
year                                  ...                                        
1800     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
1801     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
1802     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0       2.0
1803     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
1804     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

My desired output I want to look like

```
var2  (0, 1]                (1, 2]              (2, 3]              (3, 4]            ...       (15, 16]                (16, 17]                (17, 18]              (18, 19]
year                                  ...                                        
1800   <avg bin [0,1]>     <avg bin [1,2]>     <avg bin [2,3]>     <avg bin [3,4]>  ...       <avg bin [15,16]>       <avg bin [16,17]>       <avg bin [17,8]>      <avg bin [18,19]>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by the output. Why is there a year if the average is across all calendar years? In this case if you need 19 numbers, the mean for each column over all years, it's `grouped['Num_Events'].mean()`?